# Children will be children vs Children are children

Tags: tenses

Children will be children. They always have been noisy.

Why use future tense in the first sentence and present prefect tense in the second sentence? If it's same meaning to "Children are children. They are always noisy"?

Comment: The more common expression is "Boys will be boys."  This is based on a stereotype of boys' being more boisterous than girls. Anyway, the implication is "Don't expect them to act like grown-ups."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Will* here has a repetitive sense rather than a futurive sense. You have probably encountered this *will* more often in the past tense:

> When I was in high school we would always go down to the Southside Grill for cheeseburgers and shakes after school.

You can also recognize this *will* in present-tense main clauses qualified by *whenever* clauses, or *if* or *when* clauses with a *whenever* sense:

> Whenever she's annoyed she'll screw up her mouth like this and talk very flat.
>   When you plug this in the wrong socket you'll see this little blue light flashing on the main panel.

You could think of *Children will be children* as a sort of implicit *whenever* statement:

> [Whenever they are whatever,] children will be children.

A related use employs a heavily emphasized *will* to imply that somebody's annoying behavior is not merely habitual but consciously and perversely so—they *insist* on behaving this way:

> Frank **will** put commas after his conjunctions. I'm getting tired of taking them out.

This can also be used with single events; in that case it implies that the behavior is characteristic:

> If you **will** tell the Dean he's an incompetent scholar you've got to expect some repercussions.

Comment: That's excellent.  I would add only that "will be children" tends to imply  "will behave like children", whereas "are children" does not.

Comment: I'm sure this has been covered before. But this is so good I'm not going to check.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. I know I've covered pieces of it before, but I think that was on ELL, not here.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes *will* is used to describe "timeless truths," or things that are always true, in 'quaint proverbs' or other maxims:

Boys will be boys.

When the cat's away, the mouse will play.

A drowning man will clutch at straw.

Faith will move mountains.

Love will conquer all.

If you build it, he will come.

If anything can go wrong, it will.

Children will be children.

In these statements, *will* does not express future time but  *[habitual aspect](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#will)*.

You can insert the adverb *always* after "will" in any of these statements and the meaning will be the same.

Comment: +1 But "If you build it they will come" is a promise respecting a future contingency. (one of my all-time favourite movies!) ... and in most cases I think you'd be better off putting the *always* after *will*.

Comment: Of course you're right about *he* ... 'doh!

Comment: @StoneyB actually I was using the sentence in question as an axiom.